# How to set ViewPager dimensions dynamically?

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager, android-linearlayout

I have a simple question and I've searched a lot about it but still didn't have the answer. I have a viewPager and I want to set its height to half of the screen dimension. I've used setMinimumHeight() but nothing happened. How to do that ?
my XML and java code is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#d4d4d4">

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_above="@+id/product_detail_button">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/layout_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/product_detail_pictures"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"/>
 </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

My java code is

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_detail_page);
    dialogue=new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialogue.setMessage("Loading...");
    dialogue.show();

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.product_detail_pictures);

    int margin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension               

    (TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20*9, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    viewPager.setPageMargin(-margin);
    viewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
    viewPager.setMinimumHeight(height/2);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    HelperMethods.p=this;

}
```

P.S. I'm using Imageview inside viewpager to show.

Answer (score 0):

how abbout adding layout with visibility=gone ..set layout weight=1 for this layout and for the view pager ...and programatically change visibility when you need to change the viewpager height ... i will give you the xml layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/pager"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#dddddd"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    >


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
                android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:background="#33b5e5"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp">
        </android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip>
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffd60001"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/mylayout"
        android:visibility="visible"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

when you change the layout visibility to VISIBLE the view pager height will be exactly the half of the screen

from java you do this

```
(findViewById(R.id.mylayout)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); or View.GONE
```

[image: when layout is visible]
[image: when hiding the layout]

Comment: this is the easiest way i guess, try it and tell me if this is what you need